# Node.js Express Restful Api cannot get angular http post json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I have been having trouble accessing the data that is passed to express restful service from angular http service.(i build this web app with angular + node + express + mongodb)

While I using angular to post data to rest service, it cannot get my post json data, but when I using POSTMAN to post the data then it is working....

how can it be ?
is anything I missing in restful server side??

this is reply when angular post json

```
{
    __v: 0, 
    _id: "59e854e9895ea424b40471a9", 
    updateTime: "2017-10-19T07:31:53.301Z", 
    createTime: "2017-10-19T07:31:53.301Z"
}
```

this is reply when postman post json

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "uuid": "123",
    "major": 10029,
    "minor": 18910,
    "bluetoothAddress": "123",
    "createBy": "root",
    "updateBy": "root",
    "_id": "59e852ab4297be32902bae1d",
    "updateTime": "2017-10-19T07:22:19.417Z",
    "createTime": "2017-10-19T07:22:19.417Z"
}
```

this is my angular side code

1. **controller.js**

   ```
   $scope.submitNewIbeacon = function() {
       let data = {
           uuid: $scope.inputUUID,
           major: parseInt($scope.inputMajor),
           minor: parseInt($scope.inputMinor),
           bluetoothAddress: $scope.inputBluetoothAddress,
           createBy: $scope.loginUser,
           updateBy: $scope.loginUser
       }
       IbeaconListService.create_a_ibeacon(data)
           .then(
               function(response) {
                   var newIBeacon = response.data;
               });
   }
   ```
2. **service.js**

   ```
   app.service('IbeaconListService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

   var BASEURL = "http://localhost:3000";

   this.create_a_ibeacon = function(data) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   var config = {
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
       }
   }

   $http.post(BASEURL + "/ibeacons", data, config)
       .then(function(data) {
           deferred.resolve(data);
       }, function(error) {
           deferred.reject(error);
       })
   return deferred.promise;
   }

   }]);
   ```

and this is my nodejs code

1. **server.js**

   ```
   const express = require('express'),
       app = express(),
       port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
       fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'),
       cors = require('cors'),
       mongoose = require('mongoose'),
       ibeacon = require('./api/models/ibeaconListModel'),
       area = require('./api/models/areaListModel'),
       bodyParser = require('body-parser');

   app.use(cors());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
   app.use(bodyParser.json())

   // mongoose instance connection url connection
   mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
   // connect to MongoDB and create/use database called IbeaconDB
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/IbeaconDB');


   //importing route
   var ibeaconRoutes = require('./api/routes/ibeaconListRoutes.js');
   var areaRoutes = require('./api/routes/areaListRoutes.js');

   //register the route
   ibeaconRoutes(app);
   areaRoutes(app);

   app.listen(port);

   console.log('ibeacon RESTful API server started on: ' + port);

   app.use(function(req, res) {
       res.status(404).send({ url: req.originalUrl + ' not found' })
   });
   ```
2. **ibeaconListModel.js**

   ```
   'use strict';
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var IbeaconSchema = new Schema({
   uuid: {
       type: String
   },
   major: {
       type: Number
   },
   minor: {
       type: Number
   },
   bluetoothAddress: {
       type: String
   },
   createBy: {
       type: String
   },
   createTime: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
   },
   updateBy: {
       type: String
   },
   updateTime: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
   }
   });

   // create a model based on the schema
   module.exports = mongoose.model('Ibeacons', IbeaconSchema);
   ```
3. **ibeaconListRoutes.js**

   ```
   'use strict';
   module.exports = function(app) {
       var ibeaconList = require('../controllers/ibeaconListController');

       // ibeaconList Routes
       app.route('/ibeacons')
           .get(ibeaconList.list_all_ibeacons)
           .post(ibeaconList.create_a_ibeacon);

       app.route('/ibeacons/:ibeaconId')
           .get(ibeaconList.read_a_ibeacon)
           .put(ibeaconList.update_a_ibeacon)
           .delete(ibeaconList.delete_a_ibeacon);
   };
   ```
4. ibeaconListController.js

   ```
   'use strict';


   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
       Ibeacon = mongoose.model('Ibeacons');

   exports.list_all_ibeacons = function(req, res) {
       Ibeacon.find({}, function(err, ibeacon) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json(ibeacon);
       });
   };

   exports.create_a_ibeacon = function(req, res) {
       const doc = {
           uuid: req.body.uuid,
           major: req.body.major,
           minor: req.body.minor,
           bluetoothAddress: req.body.bluetoothAddress,
           updateBy: req.body.updateBy,
           createBy: req.body.createBy
       }
       var new_ibeacon = new Ibeacon(doc);

       console.log(new_ibeacon);
       new_ibeacon.save(function(err, ibeacon) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json(ibeacon);
       });
   };


   exports.read_a_ibeacon = function(req, res) {
       Ibeacon.findById(req.params.ibeaconId, function(err, ibeacon) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json(ibeacon);
       });
   };


   exports.update_a_ibeacon = function(req, res) {
       const doc = {
           uuid: req.body.uuid,
           major: req.body.major,
           minor: req.body.minor,
           bluetoothAddress: req.body.bluetoothAddress,
           updateBy: req.body.updateBy,
           updateTime: Date.now()
       }
       Ibeacon.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.ibeaconId }, doc, { new: true }, function(err, ibeacon) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json(ibeacon);
       });
   };


   exports.delete_a_ibeacon = function(req, res) {
       Ibeacon.remove({
           _id: req.params.ibeaconId
       }, function(err, ibeacon) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json({ message: 'Ibeacon successfully deleted' });
       });
   };
   ```

---

**Update** 10:29pm
I use custom middleware to check my request, then I found that my http method is GET ( it suppose to be POST )

**Custom Middleware**

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req);
    next();
});
```

[image: Postman vs Angular http post]

very confused @@

Comment: Check whether the POST REST API call, URL, Request headers and Request body are same in your code as well as in the POSTMAN.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath 
it is all same, url is `http://localhost:3000/ibeacons`,header is `application/json`, i think error is occur here  `req.body` but I cant find the solution

Comment: Can you inspect the data before it is posted on the client (use `debugger;` statement before posting)? Can you inspect the data on the server (pause before )? https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27 Why would you give a new object a uuid? Isn't that set on the server?

Comment: i use the custom middleware to inspect my request data
`app.use((req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req);
    next();
});`
it show my body is blank {}.
I use uuid is to record my ibeacon uuid(each group ibeacon have unique group uuid)